# How can I stop XScreenSaver from waking up on Mouse Input?

Tags: xorg, mouse, screensaver, xscreensaver

**CAVEAT:** [XScreenSaver and other screensavers have known problems with VLC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440321/3285) and [`xfce4-power-manager`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325053/3285). If you're using XFCE or VLC you may want to check out those *first*.

---

My problem is that with modern laser based mice, a slight vibration of desktop, causes mouse to send signal as "moved". So I would like to stop the XScreenSaver only with keyboard -- I could have XScreenSaver running and move the mouse with no effect on it (clicking could be ignored or not, I don't care).

Comment: Alternative I would prefer to see would be a 'deadzone' setting for mouse movement so that minor movement is ignored but large movement isn't.

Comment: Yes, this one too would be a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using xscreensaver you can adjust the number of pixels that the mouse must move before deactivating the screensaver; not sure about completely disabling the mouse though.

If you are not already using XScreenSaver within KDE [you can follow these instructions to set it up](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html#9).

Once you do that you can create a file in your home directory called `.xscreensaver` and in that file enter:

```
xscreensaver.pointerHysteresis: 20
```

With 20 being the number of pixels (10 is the default).

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer. Sorry for long response, but I had to save some time to make all the setup. In my case there is probably a bug, I set the value to 100 (the maximum) and it takes only touching mouse to get xscreensaver turn off.

Answer (score 0):

There are two values you may find useful, one checks the distance, the other the interval for time.

- `pointerPollTime` **(class Time, default 5 seconds)** When  server  extensions  are  not  in  use,  this controls how frequently xscreensaver checks to see if the mouse position or buttons have changed.
- `pointerHysteresis` **(class Integer, default 10 pixels)** If the mouse moves less than this-many pixels in a second, ignore it (do not consider that to be "activity.")  This is so that  the  screen  doesn't un-blank (or fail to blank) just because you bumped the desk.

Both of these can be set in the `~/.xscreensaver` file. See `man xscreensaver` for more information.